# Run cmd command using "runas" with credentials in C#

Tags: c#, command-line, remote-access

Similar question was asked at least a dozen times on SO and it looks that now I have exhausted most of the proposed solutions but still unable to complete the task successfully.

So what I have is the following command that I want to run in cmd:

```
xcopy /q C:\fileName.txt \\VMNAME\C$\destFolder /Y /E
```

But I need it to be executed with certain credentials. So what I was doing manually is entering the below command first:

```
runas /user:<domainName>\<userName> cmd
```

That was opening a separate cmd window and I was running the first (`xcopy`) command in that window.

What I have at the moment:

```
string strCmdText = string.Format(@"xcopy /q {0} {1} /Y /E", source, destination);

ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.FileName = "runas";
procStartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/user:<domainName>\<userName> cmd " + strCmdText);

Process.Start(procStartInfo);
```

Where the `source` and `destination` are of the below structure:

```
 source = "C:\\somePath\\fileName.txt"
 destination = "\\\\<VMName>\\C$\\somePath\\"
```

I have also tried defining `procStartInfo` with:

```
procStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Instead of:

```
procStartInfo.FileName = "runas";
```

With similar results.

At the moment, when I run the above code, it does not return any error but doesn't do what's expected either. Am I missing something or this approach is wrong?

Comment: try to enclose your command in quotes: `String.Format(@"/user:<domainName>\<userName> \"cmd /K " + strCmdText + "\"");`

Comment: Just to give you something else to try, have you tried impersonation?

Comment: @NiranjanKala Hi and thanks for your comment. I tried that but with similar results. Since the cmd window disappear so quickly I can't even see how the resulting command looks like.

Comment: @Jens Hi and thanks for your comment. I saw a couple of answers here on SO that offer that approach. I am in no way C# professional but it seemed to me a bit overkill for such a simple task as to copy a file.

Comment: How about simply setting domain, username and password settings in ProcessStartInfo? Then you won't need to bother with runas.

Comment: @Jens Will be happy to try that. Will you be able to give an example of how that might look like? What attribute should I use? Thanks.